# How to insert macro arguments into variables C++ processor?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I would like to pass arguments into variables names using the macros.

For example, I would have this code :

```
#define FOO(I,J) double varIJiable

FOO(1,2);
```

And the preprocessor would output this :

```
double var12iable;
```

Comment: Read about `##`.

Comment: out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this? If you have to type `FOO(1,2);` every single time you want to spell out the variable name, how is that better than writing `double var12iable;` in the first place?

Comment: I'm learning instruction level parallelism, so I'll have a bunch of `double var00iable; double var01iable; double var10iable;...`It it just to have a template so that I spend less time coding.

Comment: For easier searching, the `## ` operator is commonly called the "token pasting operator".

Comment: @truvaking it might cause less time coding but more time debugging. Being explicit is always good.

Comment: would it tho? i've been working on this for a while and most of my errors are from me missing a variable name...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ## operator to concatenate strings through the pre-processor

```
#define FOO(I,J) double var ## I ## J ## iable
```